# Understanding android partitions and directories permissions

Tags: file-permissions

I'm playing with mount points, directories and files permissions on a rooted MotoG1 using adb (a model without SDCard Slot), and I've come into certain behaviours I can't really understand.

Connected with shell I can see a mounted partition:

```
$ mount | grep storage              
/data/media /storage/emulated/legacy esdfs rw,relatime,upper=0:1028:660:771,derive=legacy,nosplit 0 0
```

In that directory there is a file, which belongs to root, without read persmissions for user shell:

```
shell@falcon_umts:/storage/emulated/legacy $ ls -l contacts2.db
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r   315392 2016-12-02 16:24 contacts2.db
```

Since I need to move that file to the host computer using *adb pull* command, I get root access to change the owner of that file to shell (surprisingly I find the files are located in */data/media/0*, not directly in */data/media*):

```
root@falcon_umts:/data/media/0 # ls -l contacts2.db
-rw------- root     root       315392 2016-12-02 16:24 contacts2.db

root@falcon_umts:/data/media/0 # chmod 755  contacts2.db
root@falcon_umts:/data/media/0 # ls -l contacts2.db
-rwxr-xr-x shell    shell      315392 2016-12-02 16:24 contacts2.db
```

As root, the changes to the file owner seem to be made, but when I get back to the shell account, the file keeps its previous owner.

```
root@falcon_umts:/data/media/0 # exit
shell@falcon_umts:/storage/emulated/legacy $ ls -l contacts2.db
-rw-rw---- root     sdcard_r   315392 2016-12-02 16:24 contacts2.db
```

Do you have any idea of the reason of this behaviour? On the other hand if the shell mount point is /data/media, shouldn't be the files on that directory also with root, instead of /data/media/0?

Comment: The data under the **/storage/emulated/legacy** is accessed through a particular, restrictive method called **Emulated SD Card File System**, which acts like a mask, and prevents you or any app from editing ownership or permissions of the files accessed from within it, thus adding a layer of security (and you can see it in the `mount` output `/data/media /storage/emulated/legacy esdfs [...]`). If you or an app have root permissions, though, you can directly access the unmasked, underlying filesystem and make potentially dangerous changes, as proven by the successful permission editing...

Comment: ... you yourself did, by issuing `chmod 755 contacts2.db`. The data under **/data/media** belongs to root because _it's not meant to be accessed that way_.